# PowerShell capture website data using regex and Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to capture the now playing song on this radio station when it is displayed on the website, I'm at the beginning of writing the script, so far I have the following code:

```
$webpage = (Invoke-WebRequest http://www.2dayfm.com.au).Content
$regex = [regex]"(.*nowPlayingInfo.*span)"
$regex.Match($webpage).Value.Split(">")[4].Replace("</span","")
```

This captures the website listed in the code, however there's two things an issue.

The first thing, when this code is run, it comes back with **Loading...**   Reason for this, if I look at the result of this:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest http://www.2dayfm.com.au).Content | clip
```

Paste this into notepad, if I search for "**Playing:**" it has this line:

```
<p><span class="listenHeading">Playing:</span> <span id="nowPlayingInfo">Loading...</span></p>
```

When I run the **Invoke-WebRequest** in my code, it captures the website at that point in time, and to see this in real life, navigate in a browser to http://www.2dayfm.com.au/ and look right at the top where the Now Playing song is, it says **Loading...** for a short time before the song actually loads.

The other thing I was hoping is to remove the second line of the code and clean the regex up on the first line, so I don't need to use as many Split & Replace methods.

The other way I was trying to get this to work was by copying the XPATH from Chrome inspect element, the use something like

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.2dayfm.com.au').Content | Select-Xml -XPath '//*[@id="nowPlayingInfo"]'
```

But this doesn't seem to work either, like it doesn't accept the XPATH, like the XPATH Chrome that thinks it is, is different to what PowerShell expects the XPATH to be.

Answer (score 4):

Using a scraper isn't going to work because you get just the initial html content that is downloaded. The page uses Javascript/Ajax to render the song/artist info by manipulating the DOM *after* the initial download.  However, you can use the InternetExplorer.Application COM object to do this:

```
$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate('http://www.2dayfm.com.au/')
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 } # need timeout here
$null = $ie.Document.body.innerhtml -match '\s+id\s*=\s*"nowPlayingInfo"\s*>(.*)</span'
$ie.Quit()
$matches[1]
```

Outputs:

```
Little Mix, Black Magic
```

The `$null =` bit is to just get rid of the `True` output that the `-match` operator generates (assuming the regex matches).